# Cannot Split CSV column to multiple columns in csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiple-columns

I have **5 CSV files**: my+first.csv, my+second.csv..my+fifth.csv with one column labelled as **0** which has n rows of data but the second column has data with line breaks which I want to split into **3 columns**: Name, User rating, Location. All CSV files have same type of data format. A sample of the data present:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Random Place 1 Â· |
|  | 4.5 Â· |
|  | 121 Random Street Â· |
| 2 | Random Place 2 Â· |
|  | 4.5 Â· |
|  | 121 Random Street Â· |

The code I wrote for this sample is:

```
import pandas as p

df = p.read_csv("sample+abc.csv")

b= df.columns.values.tolist()

c = df.columns.get_loc("0")

df['0']= df['0'].str.split("Â", n=1, expand = True)

print(b)
```

The result does not return separated columns. Can any one help with the code? Also I want to do this for all csv files. Can anyone help me write a loop to iterate the process?

Comment: Will you please show sample(s) of your CSV file(s)?

Comment: @richardec
I Tried adding samples since I'm new to Stack Overflow I'm not sure how I can add CSV samples in comment. I added a sample above in my question, it has 2 rows of data, second column has data in line breaks

Comment: Welcome! :) Please add them to the question, not in the comments. In the comments they're hard to deal with.

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding a sample in the question. Let me know if it's not clear yet :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood me correctly. I meant for you to add samples of each CSV file's contents. Is that feasible?

Comment: Oh, the 5 CSV files have same format. So I thought one sample would work.

Comment: Oh...I see. I misunderstood _you_. :) Instead of a table format, will you please add the sample using the literal CSV format that appears in the file? It's easier to convert to a dataframe than a table, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since noone answered my question, I'm posting how I managed to solve it:

```
df1= df["your-column-name"].str.split("\n", expand=True)
```

I used `\n` because I wanted to separate using line breaks.